# How do you apply a function to one of several columns in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with several different columns. Data in different columns is of different types.

I would like to apply a function to data in one of the columns and return the same DataFrame but with new values in the column to which the function was applied to.

Example:

If the DataFrame is

```
Letters Numbers Bools
0 a 1 True
1 b 2 False
```

After applying a function I would like to get:

```
Letters Numbers Bools
0 a 11 True
1 b 12 False
```

Comment: Sorry it's unclear why you need to apply on several columns when the following does what you want: `df['Numbers'] = df['Numbers'].apply(lambda x: int('1'+str(x)))` can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I only want to apply on one column. In your example I would get a DataFrame or Series with one column only, which I would further have to merge with the the initial DataFrame. I hoped I could avoid this by applying a function to one column and leave everything else untouched.

Comment: Nope I assign back to the original column so there is no need to merge back, also I'm applying on just that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the value directly for all values in a column:

```
df['Numbers'] = df['Numbers'] + 10
print df
```

This will add `10` to each value in the `Numbers` column. The result will be:

```
  Letters  Numbers  Bools
0       a       11   True
1       b       12  False
```